# JSTL string comparison when both strings are taken from the database

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I have a consultation table for doctors and when I log in with a doctors account I only want to display the consultations for that specific doctor. In my jsp page I tried the following, but with no luck:

```
<c:forEach var="consultation" items="${consultations}">
<c:if test = "${consultation.user.lastName == '${user.lastName}'}">    
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.patient.name}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.user.lastName} ${consultation.user.firstName}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.date}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.time}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.details}" /></td>
<td><c:out value="${consultation.prescription}" /></td>
</tr>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

But the comparison 
    
is not working. How can I do such a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really put this logic in the java code (servlet, struts action, etc) that populates the "consultations" list.

But to answer your question specifically, try:

```
<c:if test = "${consultation.user.lastName == user.lastName}">
```

Comment: The first sentence of this answer is the most important. +1